# SQL time data merging 30 minute intervals that span a time range per person per activity - time card

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working in SQL server and I have time card data that is separated into 30 minute intervals such as below. I need to be able to merge together overlapping times for each activity. I can't do MIN and MAX as there can be more than one set of activities for different time spans, such as breaks, there are generally two a day for each Employee. Any suggestions? The number of rows per activity date range is unknown/ dynamic, it can be 2 rows, 3 rows, etc., just depending on how many 30 minute intervals an activity spans.   First table is the sample data set,  Second table is the desired results

| Employee # | Activity Name | Activity Start | Activity End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Login | 3/17/2021 09:18:37 | 3/17/2021 09:26:54 |
| 1 | Break | 3/17/2021 10:43:25 | 3/17/2021 10:58:07 |
| 1 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 13:23:02 | 3/17/2021 13:30:00 |
| 1 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 13:30:00 | 3/17/2021 14:00:00 |
| 1 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 14:00:00 | 3/17/2021 14:08:00 |
| 1 | Break | 3/17/2021 17:16:23 | 3/17/2021 17:30:00 |
| 1 | Break | 3/17/2021 17:30:00 | 3/17/2021 17:31:00 |
| 1 | Logout | 3/17/2021 19:14:05 | 3/17/2021 19:16:02 |
| 2 | Login | 3/17/2021 09:03:05 | 3/17/2021 09:05:02 |
| 2 | Break | 3/17/2021 10:29:02 | 3/17/2021 10:30:00 |
| 2 | Break | 3/17/2021 10:30:00 | 3/17/2021 10:44:19 |
| 2 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 13:31:05 | 3/17/2021 14:00:00 |
| 2 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 14:00:00 | 3/17/2021 14:15:00 |
| 2 | Break | 3/17/2021 17:30:00 | 3/17/2021 17:45:00 |
| 2 | Logout | 3/17/2021 19:15:00 | 3/17/2021 19:16:00 |

| Employee # | Activity Name | Activity Start | Activity End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Login | 3/17/2021 09:18:37 | 3/17/2021 09:26:54 |
| 1 | Break | 3/17/2021 10:43:25 | 3/17/2021 10:58:07 |
| 1 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 13:23:02 | 3/17/2021 14:08:00 |
| 1 | Break | 3/17/2021 17:16:23 | 3/17/2021 17:31:00 |
| 1 | Logout | 3/17/2021 19:14:05 | 3/17/2021 19:16:02 |
| 2 | Login | 3/17/2021 09:03:05 | 3/17/2021 09:05:02 |
| 2 | Break | 3/17/2021 10:29:02 | 3/17/2021 10:44:19 |
| 2 | Lunch | 3/17/2021 13:31:05 | 3/17/2021 14:15:00 |
| 2 | Break | 3/17/2021 17:30:00 | 3/17/2021 17:45:00 |
| 2 | Logout | 3/17/2021 19:15:00 | 3/17/2021 19:16:00 |

Comment: There is no image.  Sample data *as text tables* is preferred.  Along with desired results.  And an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  I'm working on it,  first time posting a question like this and I cannot get the formatting to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this sussed, admittedly it's not pretty and no doubt a more elegant solution will be along, however the following gives you the desired results using window functions to look at the previous row data.

(note my date format is DMY)

**Test data**

```
create table test (EmpNo int, Activity varchar(10), AStart datetime, AEnd datetime)

insert into test
select 1 EmpNo, 'Login' Activity,'17/3/2021 09:18:37' Astart,'17/3/2021 09:26:54 ' AEnd union all
select 1, 'Break','17/3/2021 10:43:25','17/3/2021 10:58:07 ' union all
select 1, 'Lunch','17/3/2021 13:23:02','17/3/2021 13:30:00 ' union all
select 1, 'Lunch','17/3/2021 13:30:00','17/3/2021 14:00:00 ' union all
select 1, 'Lunch','17/3/2021 14:00:00','17/3/2021 14:08:00 ' union all
select 1, 'Break','17/3/2021 17:16:23','17/3/2021 17:30:00 ' union all
select 1, 'Break','17/3/2021 17:30:00','17/3/2021 17:31:00 ' union all
select 1, 'Logout','17/3/2021 19:14:05','17/3/2021 19:16:02 ' union all
select 2, 'Login','17/3/2021 09:03:05','17/3/2021 09:05:02 ' union all
select 2, 'Break','17/3/2021 10:29:02','17/3/2021 10:30:00 ' union all
select 2, 'Break','17/3/2021 10:30:00','17/3/2021 10:44:19 ' union all
select 2, 'Lunch','17/3/2021 13:31:05','17/3/2021 14:00:00 ' union all
select 2, 'Lunch','17/3/2021 14:00:00','17/3/2021 14:15:00 ' union all
select 2, 'Break','17/3/2021 17:30:00','17/3/2021 17:45:00 ' union all
select 2, 'Logout','17/3/2021 19:15:00','17/3/2021 19:16:00 '
```

**Results**

```
with spans as (select *, Iif(Lead(activity,1) over(partition by empno order by Astart)=Activity,0,1) span from test),
ranges as (
select *,
        case when IsNull(Lag(activity,1) over (partition by Empno order by AStart),'') ! =Activity then AStart end ActivityStart,
        case when span=1 then AEnd end ActivityEnd
    from spans s
)

select EmpNo, Activity, ActivityStart, ActivityEnd
from (
    select EmpNo, Activity, AStart, IsNull(ActivityStart,Lag(ACtivityStart,1) over(partition by empno order by Astart)) ActivityStart,  ActivityEnd
    from ranges r
    where ActivityStart is not null  or span=1
)x
where ActivityEnd is not null
```